# log scale in python pylab is making y label go off the edge

Tags: matplotlib

In other plots it just does 10^-1, 10^-2 etc, but this has this 8x10^-1 etc,

Can we force it to make it 10^-1,10^-2 etc without the leading multiplier stuff? I've just been using `plt.yscale('log')`
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can by manipulating the tick labels. Unfortunately, we can't provide answer on such poorly asked **broad question** which does not even include any code. We can just provide hints like I did in the first statement. Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you remove all the "multiplier stuff" you would end up with a single label `10^0`. An axis with a single tick is never useful. So in addition to the above comment, you will also need to explain more in detail what you want the final graph to look like.

Comment: Agree with above, but [plt.tight_layout()](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) may be what you actually want (instead of changing the ticks).